# html5 video plays on all browsers except IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer-9, html5-video

I wanted to post this question and answer because I wasn't able to find it anywhere.

So if you are playing with HTML5 `<video>` on the different browsers make sure the rest of your HTML is valid such that your video will play on IE9.

The following code works on Chrome 19, Firefox 12, Opera11, as well as iOS5 but **NOT** IE9:

```
<video controls="controls">
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: are you actually saying that you tried to make it work by just starting page with a `<video>` tag, without any html/ head/ body tag as you did instead in your answer?

Comment: Yes, I think so. It's been awhile now, but at the time I think I remember just the <video> tag being sufficient to work in chrome, safari, and firefox whereas I needed the full HTML5 markup to get IE to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get it to play on IE9,

You need this full markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>
<video controls="controls">
   <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

First check whether your browser support HTML 5 Video or not

[Check browser supporting video or not](http://html5test.com/)

Comment: -@aliAdravi can you add to your answer how people should do that programmatically? This is in case the link breaks.