# HTML5 video in IE9 shows poster image but does not play

Tags: html

i'm using the code below which works fine in Chrome, Safari, FF and IE8 (using http://html5media.info/)

```
    <video width="388" height="232" poster="images/transparent.png" controls preload>
      <source src="assets/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      <source src="assets/video.webm" type="video/webm">
    </video>
```

IE9 shows the poster but no controls. If I click on the poster image, nothing happens. If I right click on the poster image, I get the option to play video and then the video starts playing. Any ideas how I can get the controls to show up on IE9? Thanks

Comment: Are you using html5 doctype ?

Comment: Did `<video src="assets/video.mp4" controls></video>` work ?

Comment: @tea_totaler - yes, html5 doctype

Comment: Please see this past question/answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744438/html5-video-plays-on-all-browsers-except-ie9

Comment: @DanGoodspeed - did you read the question?

Comment: @yakiang - thanks, i tried that but didn't work